# How to only multiply certain values in R column?

Tags: r, multiplication

I am trying to make a column easier to read. Right now, the data looks like this (also this is my first time using stackoverflow.com so ignore any wrong formatting!):

```
**Money**
16k 
42.3k
15
8900
```

This is currently being read as character values and not numeric. I want to have all these values standardized, so I want to get rid of the "k". I thought I would do this:

```
data$money<- data$money %>% 
  str_replace('k', '') %>% 
  as.numeric()
```

But now  my issue is getting the values to show up correctly. So for example, 16k is actually is 16,000 but 42.3k is actually 42,300 and I cannot do:

`data$money <- data$money * 1000`

because it would be inaccurate since 15 and 8900 should be kept as 15 and 8900, and not 15,000 and 8,900,000. Any tips on what to do? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

#### A better option which eliminates the need for `eval(parse(`:

Use `gsub` to replace the `k` with the scientific notation symbol for mutiplying by a factor of ten. The normal R number conversion recognizes that and will convert it to a number properly:

```
x = c('16k','42.3k','15','8900')

as.numeric(gsub('k', 'e3', x))
[1] 16000 42300    15  8900
```

You can deal with other suffixes by nesting further gsub calls. For example, to also handle `M` for million:

```
y = c('16k','42.3k','15','8900', '2.1M')

as.numeric(gsub('k', 'e3', gsub('M', 'e6', y)))
[1]   16000   42300      15    8900 2100000
```

To use it with a dataframe, just select the column with `$` and use it in place of x or y:

```
data <- structure(list(money = c("16k", "42.3k", "15", "8900")),
    row.names = c(NA, -4L),class = "data.frame")

data$money <- as.numeric(gsub('k', 'e3', gsub('M', 'e6', data$money)))
data
  money
1 16000
2 42300
3    15
4  8900
```

---

I'm not sure if this is the best option, but it's pretty simple and handles the decimals too. We use a regex to replace `k` with `*1000` (the operation: times 1000), then evaluate the strings to complete the multiplication:

```
x = c('16k','42.3k','15','8900')

sapply(gsub('k', '*1000', x), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))

  16*1000 42.3*1000        15      8900 
    16000     42300        15      8900
```

You can deal with other suffixes by nesting further `gsub` calls, for example to convert `M` to `*1000000` before evaluating.

Obviously, be careful using this in production code where a user could insert possibly malicious code into `data$money` which could be run. But for your purposes, this should be fine.

Comment: I tried this but it gave me NAs - is it because the data is a column in a df?

Comment: @ALLW Maybe. If you select a specific column in a dataframe with `$` it should give a vector. So using `data$money` in place of `x` should work unless there's some other issue in your data which I can't see from your examples. Can you share a [mcve] of your actual dataframe? You can use `dput(head(data))` and paste that into the question

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how rigorous you want to be.  If you have several symbols (like `"k"` for `1000`), you might consider a mapping.

## Solution

Start by defining a mapping from each (textual) `symbol` to its (numeric) conversion `scale`.

```
# Define a mapping from symbols like "k" to conversion scales like 1000.
scale_mapping <- data.frame(
  symbol = c("k" ),
  scale  = c(1000)
)
```

Then simply apply this workflow in the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org):

```
# Load the 'tidyverse'.
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  # Split the 'money' column into one column for the number and another for the symbol.
  extract(
    money,
    c("money", NA, "money_symbol"),

    # A rigorous regex: match only a number with an optional decimal, followed by an
    # optional alphabetic symbol; no spaces are permitted (but you can adjust that).
    "^(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)([A-Za-z]+)?$"
  ) %>%
  
  # Map any symbols to their conversion scale.
  left_join(
    scale_mapping,
    by = c("money_symbol" = "symbol")
  ) %>%
  
  # Convert to the appropriate scale.
  mutate(
    # First interpret the 'money' text as numbers.
    money = as.numeric(money),

    # Multiply by a scale if available.
    money = if_else(is.na(scale), money, money * scale)
  ) %>%
  
  # Discard the helper columns.
  select(!c(money_symbol, scale))
```

## Results

Given a dataset like your `data`, reproduced here

```
data <- structure(
  list(
    money = c("16k", "42.3k", "15", "8900")
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -4L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

this solution should yield the following `data.frame`:

```
  money
1 16000
2 42300
3    15
4  8900
```

## Warning

Be sure to use consistent case for your symbols.  As it stands, `"K"` will not match `"k"`, though they both can represent a `scale` of `1000`.  If you have mixed cases in `data`, then consider either

1. standardizing `money_symbol` with (say) `%>% mutate(money_symbol = tolower(money_symbol))` right after [`extract()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html); **or**
2. using a [`fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join`](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzyjoin/man/regex_join.html)`(..., ignore_case = TRUE)` in place of the [`left_join`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html)`(...)`.